# Node Specific Parameters in YAML

Tags: ros, yaml, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now, for every node I am creating a yaml file and put all the parameters inside and call this file in the launch file under the corresponding node.

Is it possible to create only one yaml file where I can specify name tags for parameters? Something like;

```
Node name:

param1: 1.0
param2: 2.0

Node name2:

param1: 3.0
param2: 4.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248975/node-specific-parameters-in-yaml/) by [emreay](https://answers.ros.org/users/12731/emreay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The yaml is not associated with any particular node, but more to do with namespaces. That is, a yaml that looks like:

```
settings:  # Arbitrary settings
  camera:
    format: "jpeg"
  wheels:
    max_speed: 3.0
    min_speed: 0.2
```

would create three values in the parameter service. If you type in `rosparam list`, you would get:

```
/settings/camera/format
/settings/wheels/max_speed
/settings/wheels/min_speed
```

(You can get the actual values with `rosparam get [param]`).

The point of this is that a node can get any of these parameters. In your launch file, instead of putting the `<rosparam>` tag inside the node (which I understand you have), you can have it at the top. Something like:

```
<launch>
  <rosparam file="$(find package1)/config/settings.yaml" command="load" />
  <node pkg="package1" type="node1" name="node1" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [petern3](https://answers.ros.org/users/28607/petern3/) with karma: 186 on 2016-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emreay](https://answers.ros.org/users/12731/emreay/) on 2016-11-29**:
Thank you..